# Is GSON using a cache mechanism to enhance encoding time for objects

Tags: java, json, caching, gson

I'm using GSON Library to encode java objects to JSON Strings and I am interested in how this works. I can suggest that GSON is using a cache mechanism to speedup the encoding, but I can't find a source of knowledge about that topic. In GSON documentation there is no information about it.

Could someone find information about cache behavior of GSON?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: "can't find a source of knowledge about that topic", "there is no information about it" - Take that as a strong hint that there is no such caching mechanism in GSON.

Comment: but there are signs which say there is a caching mechanism. The more messages I'm sending, the faster encoding and decoding will work. But maybe it's just a optimization of the jvm.

but such a caching mechanism would make sense. If I decode 2million objects, GSON could remember the object structure and where to find every attribute in the json string. otherwise gson have to parse the json string everytime and that's really heavy.

Comment: "GSON could remember [...] where to find every attribute in the json string" - How'd that work? Are you talking about decoding the same JSON string into objects over and over again?

Comment: @JimmyB no, but thecoding the same key value structure, so the keys are mostly the same, only the values differ